# Distributing fire stations in a circular city

Tags: graph-theory

How to distribute k points inside a disc so to minimize the distance of any point inside the disc to the closest of the k points? 
Does this problem have a name?
Is the solution a famous sequence of geometric graphs?

Comment: Instead of circle, do you mean disk?

Comment: Yes, pardon for the imprecision.

Answer (score 10):

This is the (finite) covering problem in the plane. According to Böröczky's book *Finite packing and covering*, the answer is only known (provably) up to $k = 10$, due to the work of K. Bezdek and G. Fejes Toth. I don't know if the solutions are a famous sequence of geometric graphs.

[image]
<sub>(Image from [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskCoveringProblem.html) added by J.O'Rourke [(source)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/DiskCoveringProblem5_800.gif))</sub>

Comment: More from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_covering_problem

Comment: Thanks a lot Joseph, this seems to be a good solution but I'm not convinced same radius circles are always the best solution, do you think this can be/has been shown?

Comment: Minimising the distance to the nearest centre is equivalent to covering by smallest disks of equal radius.

Comment: I understand it, but could you provide a proof or refer to a place where I can find it?